# In Finicast, I am unable to apply my formula on a group of cells in my pivot table

Tags: pivot-table, business-intelligence

I was trying to build a periods model using Finicast. I am stuck at this step where I apply a formula to the cells with dimension `'Fcst'` and `'Revenue'` in my pivot table.
Based on my understanding, if I select `Revenue` cell for month of `Jul22`, the formula `THIS("idx")` should have been applied and the cell should contain the value `7` instead of `0`. I have other formulas applied to this cell. But I have my `rev_fcst` formula top precedence to apply on this cell. Irrespective of which order I apply the formulas in, in this selection, the value for `months` & `Revenue` cells remain `0`.

What am I missing here?

I have added images of my formula bar, pivot table, and dimensions

[The formula bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JppkW.png)

[The rows highlighted by selecting Fcst and Revenue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsSe6.png)

[periods table for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4yHg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the image you posted, you have a set of "hardcoded" 0's for Jul22, Aug22 and Sep22.  Click on those cells and press the Delete key to remove the hardcodes, and then the underlying formula will show-up again.